# Login with PayPal Sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Working on a Login with PayPal integration using their sandbox environment. One requirement when obtaining the initial authorization code, you supply a `redirect_url` in the query string. That url must roughly (protocol,port,hostname) match the redirect URL in the sandbox.

When filling out a return URL in the sandbox, the form says "Something went wrong. Try again later" after submitting for the first time. Upon the second submission, the request just times out altogether.

Meanwhile, when trying to initiate the Login with PayPal flow, it warns that:

`Relying Party Validation error: redirect_uri provided in the request does not match with the registered redirect_uri. Please check the request.`

Has anyone found a workaround for this or experienced this issue in the sandbox?

Comment: Hey ChrisW, I was able to reproduce the issue on my local machine. I will let you know once I have the answer. But for now, there is indeed an issue on sandbox, that is causing unnecessary failure on sandbox environment.

Answer (score 0):

As Jay Patel mentioned, there has been an issue effecting users of payPals sandbox.  It now appears like it could be fixed ([see PayPal Community](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Payments/After-completing-transaction-Paypal-Is-not-redirecting-to-the/td-p/953168)).

Can you attempt to run the script again to see if that was the issue?